# tensorflow u-net python package filter map dimention

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

is it possible to change the filter map dimension of the first layer of a CNN and increase it by 1 ( instead of 5*5*64) I want it to be (5*5*33*64) in a python u-net package? I want my batch size to be 33 so that I could use a 2D unet for a 3D image with 33 slices

Answer (score 0):

If you are reusing weights trained for 2D images you will lose any correlation between voxels in the z-dimension.

If you are planning to train a new U-net for 3D images you might as well just take a pre-existing implementation like [this](https://github.com/ellisdg/3DUnetCNN) and then you only have to worry about correct data processing and training

but in either case it is possible